# redis script check if hash field exists

Tags: lua, redis

The question is about *lua script* in redis.

I'm trying to check if some field exists in a hash table, but the return value of `redis.call` suprised me:

```
    EVAL 'local label = "oooo"; local tesid = redis.call("HGET", "nosuchkey", "nosuchfield"); if tesid == nil then label="aaaa" elseif tesid == "" then label="bbbb" else label = "kkkk" end; return {tesid,label}' 0
```

the return value is

```
    1) (nil)
    2) "kkkk"
```

I don't understand why I got into that `else` branch -- where `label` is set to `"kkkk"` -- when tesid is `nil`, I think it should output `"aaaa"`.

Why does the script go into `"kkkk"` label?

For better reading, I paste the script here:

```
    local label = "oooo"
    local tesid = redis.call("HGET", "nosuchkey", "nosuchfield")
    if tesid == nil
    then
        label="aaaa"
    elseif tesid == ""
    then
        label="bbbb"
    else
        label = "kkkk"
    end
    return {tesid,label}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** `tesid` is `false` **NOT** `nil`.

Redis' conversion rules for `nil` reply is as follows:

1. Redis `nil` reply is converted to Lua `false` boolean type.
2. Lua `false` boolean type is converted to Redis' `nil` reply.

In your case, `HGET` returns `nil`, which is converted to `false`. So `tesid` is `false`. It's not equal to either `nil` or `""`, so `label` is set to `kkk`. When your code returns `tesid` as part of the return value, it's converted to Redis' `nil` reply. And that's why you got `{nil, kkk}`

Comment: I read [introduction to eval](https://redis.io/commands/eval#introduction-to-eval) again, with your statements in mind, then I got a different understanding about *Lua data types are converted into the Redis protocol when calling a Redis command and when a Lua script returns a value*. Here *when calling a Redis command* must mean `redis.call` in script.